# Add an object by id in a ManyToMany relation in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, many-to-many

[Django's ManyToMany field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) can be populated using `my_field.add(my_instance)`, but as I understand it only `my_instance.id` is actually needed to perform the corresponding SQL query.

If I want to add an object by its id, I can use `my_field.add(MyModel.objects.get(id=id))`, but this will generate two queries instead of one. How can I avoid this extra query?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Although [the documentation of the `add` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) does not mention it, you can actually pass directly an id to it, like this:

```
my_instance.add(id)
```

Surely, this only works when the primary key is used as the identifier for the relation (the default behaviour).

Comment: Passing the id directly results in a TypeError for me (Django 1.10.5): "TypeError: 'MyRelatedModel' instance expected, got '5835da11-dcde-47da-9664-e5c13e235ccc'"

Comment: in 2.2 docs now mention this: "add() also accepts the field the relation points to as an argument. The above example can be rewritten as b.entry_set.add(234).'

Comment: hmm..  it seems using an id works slightly differently.  If the relation already exists then it throws an `IntegrityError` where adding the object just ignores the existing relation.

Comment: So, I'm not quite right.... You need to make sure the pk is of the same type that's expected or you get `IntegrityError`.  For example, if you do `.add('3')` and the id should be an integer you will get an error if the relation already exists.  If you do `.add(3)` then it will ignore the duplicate.