# add value in table manytomany django

Tags: django, api, many-to-many

hi i try to add same value in a table many to many in django but i don't know how can i do it

this is my modles:

```
class Raza(models.Model):
     Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     Origen = models.CharField(max_length=45)
     Altura = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     Peso = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     Esperanza_vida = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     Actividad_fisica = models.CharField(max_length=45)
     Recomendaciones = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     Clasificacion_FCI = models.ForeignKey(Clasificacion_FCI,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     Tipo_pelo = models.ManyToManyField(Tipo_pelo,blank=True)
     Caracteristicas_fisicas = models.ManyToManyField(Caracteristicas_fisicas,blank=True)
     Caracter = models.ManyToManyField(Caracter,blank=True)
     Ideal = models.ManyToManyField(Ideal,blank=True)
     Tamanio = models.ForeignKey(Tamanio,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     User = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True)
```

and the User model are the default model that Django give me

i tried someone like that

```
class AgregarFav(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        idUsario= request.POST.get('isUsuario')
        idPerro = request.POST.get('idPerro')
        raza = Raza.User.add(idPerro,idUsario)
        raza.save()
        return HttpResponse(idUsario)
```

but i have the error 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'

i want do something like that

```
table user 
id_usuario = 1
name = "Juan"

table raza
id_raza = 1 
name = "pitbull"

table user_raza
id_user_raza = 1
id_user = 1
id_raza = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't name fields of your model starting with uppercase letter because of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Rename `User` to `users` (as your m2m connection means multiple instances on both sides), apply migrations and add instances of `User` to instance of `Raza` like this:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=usario_id)
Raza.objects.get(id=perro_id).users.add(user)
```

[Django m2m add docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add).

edit:

Actually you can add users not by instances but with pks. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511421/add-an-object-by-id-in-a-manytomany-relation-in-django).

Answer (score 0):

You edit the relation of a *specific* object, like:

```
Raza.objects.get(id=idPerro).User.add(idUsario)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways of adding m2m relation.

**1. Single attachment.**

```
user = User.objects.get(id=usario_id)
r1 = Raza.objects.get(id=1)

user.razas.add(r1)
```

**2. Bulk**

```
user = User.objects.get(id=usario_id)
razas = []

p1 = Raza.objects.get(id=1)
p2 = Raza.objects.get(id=2)
razas.append(p1)
razas.append(p2)

user.razas.add(*razas)
```